# Show that $\exp(-\exp(\log(-\log(\hat{S}(t)))+A)=\hat{S}(t)^{\exp(A)}$

Tags: statistics, logarithms, exponential-function, self-learning, confidence-interval

> Let $L(t)=\log(-\log S(t))$ where $S(t)$ is a survival function. Then
>   a confidence interval for $S(t)=\exp(-\exp(L(t))$ is given by 
>   $$[\exp(-\exp(\hat{L}(t)+A));\exp(-\exp(\hat{L}(t)-A));$$ and taking
>   $\hat{L}(t)=\log(-\log (\hat{S}(t)))$ the confidence interval is
>   $$[\hat{S}(t)^{e^{A}};\hat{S}(t)^{e^{-A}}]$$
>
> where $A=\sigma(\hat{L}(t)$)
>
> This result can be found here
>   http://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/DOCS/Notes/TS16/train16.pdf slide number
>   13.

I already understood the expression for the variance of the estimator, but the problem is the resulting confidence interval.

$$\exp(-\exp(\hat{L}(t)+A))=\exp(-\exp(\log(-\log(\hat{S}(t)))+A)$$

$$=\exp(\log(\hat{S}(t))\times \exp(A))=\hat{S}(t)^{\exp(A)}$$

I do not know if it is solved that way or if I forced the result. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did the A come down out of the inner exponent at the end?

Comment: @Glen_b In the result or in what I tried? I get this confidence interval for $\log(-log(\hat{S}(t)))$ in a book but I don't understand how they get it.

Comment: in your second-last expression you have $e^{-e^A}$ as the last term. In the next expression you have $e^{-eA}$. How did you do that?

Comment: @Glen_b I made a correction, but I don't know if I solved it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks okay to me.

It's not clear to me what "forced the result" means - if it's a valid manipulation of the expression, it's a valid manipulation.

You'd do the same kind of thing for the lower bound.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure if the manipulation of the expression is correct.